# Remove text indent from list items AND fix :after function (IE7 and down) CSS

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I have been trying to fix my drop-down menu for IE versions 7 and down. I am almost done except that I am unable to remove the indent from the list items. I tried a bunch of things like padding: 0, margin: 0, list-style-position: inside,... without any luck.

See this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQG3q.jpg

Also, I have another issue with the same versions of IE. This happens when I hover my mouse over a list item below the first row which reveals another list item to it's right. If I don't hover my mouse back up the same path and exit the menu by the same first row item, blank list items show if I choose the same item from the first row again. I know this might be confusing but I took a screenshot to show the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdcPs.jpg

I would think this issue is related to the :after function not being read correctly in the CSS file but I'm not sure.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Tires
                <ul>
                    <li>Utility
                        <ul>
                            <li>Gripper</li>
                            <li>Radical</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Sport
                        <ul>
                            <li>Race-X</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Contact
                <ul>
                    <li>About us</li>
                    <li>Contact us</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Dealers
                <ul>
                    <li>Locate a dealer</li>
                    <li>Become a dealer</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Downloads</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS code:

```
#menu {
    height: 36px;
    width: 960px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px #888;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px #888;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
    background: #333;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

#menu ul {
    background: #333;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

#menu ul:after {
    content: ""; 
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
}

#menu ul li {
    width: 190px;
    border: 1px solid #2a2a2a;
    background: #333;
    float: left;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
    background: #1B1B1B;
}

#menu ul li.active {
    background: #1B1B1B;
}

#menu ul li a {
    display: block; 
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul ul {
    width: 189px;
    background: #333;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 100%;
}

#menu ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #494949;
    border-right: 1px solid #494949;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #494949;
    list-style-position:inside;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#menu ul ul li:hover {
    background: #868686;
    color: #FFF;
}

#menu ul ul li a {
    line-height: 34px;
    height: 34px;
}   

#menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #868686;
}

#menu ul ul ul {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Ie7 and down? Are those still alive?

Comment: Apparently yes! When I try accessing the website from work (IE7) the menu is screwed up!

Comment: 1) Intranet? -> set x-ua-compatible meta tag. 2) IE6 does not support pseudoelements, so you won't be able to fix it that easily for this browser 3) tell your admin that IE7 is a severe security risk and he should upgrade to at least IE8 (apparently you are running xp) asap! 4) I wouldn't mind ppl with old browsers having problems - it's not worth the time you invest in this issue.